# Group BY while getting SUM of Bit columns

Tags: sql-server, casting, group-by, sum, case

I have a SQL query that returns each employment entry they entered and rather or not they chose to allow to contact the employer or not, also the id associated with that person. This is how the table looks:

```
full_name               number_of_dnc_ver   user_profile_id
FATest FATesterlast     No                  260054
FATest FATesterlast     Yes                 260054
FATest FATesterlast     No                  260059
FATest FATesterlast     Yes                 260059
FATest FATesterlast     No                  260064
FATest FATesterlast     Yes                 260064
Domenic Wiley           Yes                 260220
Harold Rojas            Yes                 261550
Harold Rojas            Yes                 262186
Harold Rojas            Yes                 262287
testvvi0236 testvvi0236 No                  263692
Harold Rojas            Yes                 263878
Harold Rojas            Yes                 263893
```

The result I'm trying to get is to GROUP BY the user_profile_id(same names but different ids), cast the "number_of_dnc_ver" as a bit column and get the sum of . So for FATest FATesterlast with 260054, the result would be the name, 1 and ID.

This is what I figured out so far and I'm close:

```
SELECT [tbl_User_Profile].[first_name] + ' ' + [tbl_User_Profile].[last_name] AS full_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(MAX),DecryptByKey([tbl_Results].[default_value_binary])) = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_dnc_ver,
       tbl_User_Profile].[user_profile_id]
FROM tbl_Results
INNER JOIN tbl_Controls ON tbl_Results.control_id = tbl_Controls.control_id
INNER JOIN tbl_Default_Controls ON tbl_Controls.default_control_id = tbl_Default_Controls.default_control_id
INNER JOIN tbl_User_Profile ON tbl_User_Profile.user_profile_id = tbl_Results.user_profile_id
WHERE (tbl_User_Profile.application_id = 3707
       AND tbl_Controls.control_name LIKE 'rbl_ContactEmployer_%')
GROUP BY [tbl_User_Profile].[user_profile_id],
         [tbl_User_Profile].[first_name] + ' ' + [tbl_User_Profile].[last_name]
```

This is close to how I want it, but obviously its not including  bunch of names for some reason.

```
full_name               number_of_dnc_ver user_profile_id 
Domenic Wiley           1                 260220 
Ha Ro                   2                 262287 
testvvi0236 testvvi0236 0                 263692
Harold Rojas            1                 263902 
FATest FATesterlast     1                 260054 
FATest FATesterlast     1                 260059 
Harold Rojas            1                 263878 
Harold Rojas            1                 261550
Harold Rojas            1                 263893 
Harold Rojas            1                 263907
FATest FATesterlast     1                 260064 
Harold Rojas            1                 262186
```

Comment: Can it be because of your INNER joins?   Maybe there are no matching rows in one of the joined tables?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is missing. In fact the result set seems to have extra data. Also you should probably remove that group with the concatenation. just change the `+ ' ' +` to a comma there should be no reason to do a concat in a group by clause.

Comment: @KHeaney I needed it to group by the entire full name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is lost after the `JOINS`, possible reason is that , either `tbl_Controls` or `tbl_Default_Controls` or `tbl_User_Profile` is missing, the equivalent data from `tbl_Results`.

Can you try this query. I commented out `tbl_Default_Controls` as it is not used in `where` condition/`Select`

```
SELECT      P.[first_name] + ' ' + P.[last_name] AS full_name,
            SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(MAX),DecryptByKey(R.[default_value_binary])) = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_dnc_ver,
            P.[user_profile_id]
FROM        tbl_Results R
INNER JOIN  tbl_Controls C ON R.control_id = C.control_id
--INNER JOIN    tbl_Default_Controls DC ON C.default_control_id = DC.default_control_id
INNER JOIN  tbl_User_Profile P ON P.user_profile_id = R.user_profile_id
WHERE       (P.application_id = 3707 AND C.control_name LIKE 'rbl_ContactEmployer_%')
GROUP BY    P.[user_profile_id],
            P.[first_name] + ' ' + P.[last_name]
```

Comment: `SELECT                        
[tbl_User_Profile].[first_name] + ' ' + [tbl_User_Profile].[last_name] AS full_name
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(MAX),DecryptByKey([tbl_Results].[default_value_binary])) = 'Yes' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS dnc_verifications
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(MAX),DecryptByKey([tbl_Results].[default_value_binary])) = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_verifications
   ,[tbl_User_Profile].[user_profile_id]`


This got me what I was looking for. code formatting in comments suck